# Hyperref: possible page numbering conflict with \alph and \roman

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering

I remember reading somewhere (can't seem to find the actual page now) that in order to avoid duplicate references with `hyperref` one should switch the page numbering to an "unused" one (say, `\alph`) for unnumbered pages (eg. the title pages, copyright pages, etc.).

Additionally, one usually uses roman numbers (say, `\roman`) for the front matter (eg. table of contents, list of figures/tables, introductions, etc.).

It just crossed my mind that, where one to have a longish front matter, this two numberings could clash and you would still get duplicate references. For example, suppose you have 10 unnumbered pages "numbered" a through j, and suppose you have 60 pages of front matter numbered i to dx: wouldn't the "d" in the unnumbered part clash with the "d" in the front matter? is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You'd have already a conflict with "i". My opinion is that *all* pages should have a number (the "outer" frontispiece makes an exception) and all pages should have the same numbering scheme. Numbering front matter pages with Roman numbers is a tradition that nowadays has no reason: it used to be necessary because nobody could know in advance the number of pages in the front matter, which was thus typeset last.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, there can still be a clash of page numbers, although it is unlikely under normal circumstances. But it can be easily avoided: just modify the "invisible" page numbers to contain something that can never be part of a roman numeral. The following example introduces a new page numbering style `myalph`, which does nothing but prepend a `z` to the `alph` output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@myalph}{z\@alph}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{myalph}
\setcounter{page}{9}
test

\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

There are five "standard" page numbering styles: `arabic`, `roman`, `Roman`, `alph`, `Alph`, and `fnsymbol`. When there is a clash between `alph` and `roman` (i, v, x, l, c, d, m), you could use `alph` and `Roman` or `Alph` and `roman` or `alph`/`Alph` and `fnsymbol` without the need to redefine anything. (If you are using yet another page numbering style for the backmatter, you might still have to use Vihrov's solution, of course.)